# Keep getting an error on this program

Tags: python, format

```
L1 = [7, 106, 17, 1, 28, 103]
L2 = [6, 44, 201, 66, 32, 71]
L1.sort()
L2.sort()
L3 = []
while L1 or L2:
    if L1[-1] < L2[-1]:
        L3.append(L2.pop())
    else:
        L3.append(L1.pop())
        if len(L1) == 0:
            L3 += L2
            break
        if len(L2) == 0:
            L3 += L1
            break
print(L3)
```

I get the error below, but dont know why I keep getting this error.
    //line 7, in 
    if L1[-1] < L2[-1]:
    IndexError: list index out of range//

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seem to be in the condition on which the while loop continues: L1 or L2 means that only one of those has to be a non-empty list.

Your code fails when one of those lists becomes and empty list, but the other one does not.

You might want to change (if this is okay for your requirements) the condition from

```
L1 or L2
```

to

```
L1 and L2
```

### Best regards,

Znpy

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are just trying to combine two lists together and have the result reverse-sorted. If so, the following should be a lot simpler:

```
L1 = [7, 106, 17, 1, 28, 103]
L2 = [6, 44, 201, 66, 32, 71]
L3 = sorted(L1 + L2, reverse=True)
print(L3)
```

If you would rather use your approach, the issue in your code is just one of indentation. Your `len(L1)` and `len(L2)` checks were only happening in your `else` condition. This should fix it:

```
L1 = [7, 106, 17, 1, 28, 103]
L2 = [6, 44, 201, 66, 32, 71]
L1.sort()
L2.sort()
L3 = []
while L1 or L2:
    if L1[-1] < L2[-1]:
        L3.append(L2.pop())
    else:
        L3.append(L1.pop())
    if len(L1) == 0:
        L3 += L2
        break
    if len(L2) == 0:
        L3 += L1
        break
print(L3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L1 = [7, 106, 17, 1, 28, 103]
L2 = [6, 44, 201, 66, 32, 71]
L1.sort()
L2.sort()
L3 = []
while L1 or L2:
    if L1[-1] < L2[-1]:
        L3.append(L2.pop())
    else:
        L3.append(L1.pop())
    if len(L1) == 0:
        L3 += L2
        break
    if len(L2) == 0:
        L3 += L1
        break
print(L3)
```

> output: [201, 106, 103, 71, 66, 44, 32, 28, 17, 7, 6, 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep a check for length of lists and then use 'and' in the while statement.

```
def merge(L1,L2):
   L1 = [7, 106, 17, 1, 28, 103]
   L2 = [6, 44, 201, 66, 32, 71]
   L1.sort()
   L2.sort()
   L3 = []
   if len(L1) == 0 and len(L2) == 0:
      return []
   while L1 and L2:
      if L1[-1] < L2[-1]:
         L3.append(L2.pop())
      else:
         L3.append(L1.pop())
         if len(L1) == 0:
            L3 += L2
            break
         if len(L2) == 0:
            L3 += L1
            break
   print(L3)

merge(L1, L2)
```